# Rendering equal width buttons in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flexbox

I want to render 7 buttons in a row with equal width to fill up all the available space horizontally.

```
render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.days}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.button}><Button title={item.getDate().toString()} /></View>}
            keyExtractor={item => item.getDate().toString()}
            horizontal={true}
            style={styles.list}
        />
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        display: 'flex'
    },
    button: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

They are inside a flatlist, wrapped in a view because I cannot style buttons directly.
In regular flexbox in an HTML page this approach works.

This what I get in React Native:

[image]

Maybe there are some flatlist behaviour I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue, I have added View component cover for each Button like the code below:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
    <View  style={{flex:1}}>
        <Button title="Add"  />
    </View>
    <View  style={{flex:1}}>
        <Button title="Clear"  />
    </View>
    //....
</View>
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all when you are styling in react native everything is already in flex so you don't have to do `display : flex`

If you want to render 7 buttons with the same width in a row make sure that all of them have the same parent. Then use `flex:1` in each one of them.

What is happening when you do `flex:1` when you put a number in front of `flex` in your styles in this particular situation it divides your parent into those many parts and give it to the child.

So all your button will have 1/7th of the width. If you put `flex:2` in one of the styles then that button will have 2/7th of the width and the rest will have 1/7th.

Please feel free to ask for more clarity on the above said.

Comment: Yes I understand what `flex: 1` does. So, in my case it should give the the `<View>` elements 1/7th of the width. But it does not. Maybe Flatlist is not the direct parent of the `<View>` elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `flex: 1` to the list so that it takes up the entire horizontal space?

Answer (score 0):

in my point of view, try adding `justifyContent` as `space-between` in the style object **list**

Answer (score 0):

in each item ,set this style:

```
width:width/7
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `React Native Elements`, we need to add `flex:1` to `containerStyle` of button.